# SQL Server client codes and client names discrepancy based on the 1st number of the client code linked to different clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got a table with client codes and client names. The client codes used before were e.g.**M**1003993. They were updated, and now client codes are created starting with **7**1003993. The client names linked to these client codes (both M, 7) are different clients names, so I cannot filter discrepancy in client codes based on the same client name.

What I need is how to get extracted 1 DISTINCT client code with linked to it client name (**M**1003993) and join it to the similar DISTINCT client code with its own DISTINCT client name (**7**1003993) meaning that I need a reference list of codes where 1st letter or number of the client code is different whilst the rest 7 numbers are the same? All this is done within 1 table.

My guess is that the same table should be joined back to itself, but how to create this cross-reference when we have (**7**1003993) and (**M**1003993) codes with different client names.

Image below shows SELECT, maybe it will help to explain what I mean

[image]

I need to identify client names for both codes M and 7, so 71003993 (client name 1 ) = M1003993 (client name 2), and this is for 260,000 records

Comment: Please clarify whether you are using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server; you have tags for both.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Pls provide some sample data and expected output as a minimum! It's a bit difficult to interpret what you are after

Comment: @Igor, if you are saying "how would I link 'M1003000' to '71003000'" then that is ok, but what is the link between M1003000 and 71003993?  in the first case you can do a join by knocking the first character off using RIGHT and LEN for example

Comment: SELECT 'M1003000' X, '71003993' Y INTO TT

select *, RIGHT(X,LEN(x) - 1), RIGHT(y,LEN(y) - 1) , left(x,1), left(y,1) from tt

Answer (score 1):

if the last 7 letters of the client code is same ,use the below code.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable y1
  JOIN yourTable y2 On RIGHT(y1.clientcode,7)= RIGHT(y2.clientcode,7)
 WHERE y1.clientcode like 'M%' AND y2.clientcode like '7%'
```

Comment: Hi Unnikrishnan, thank you!! Yes, this is it:  

SELECT DISTINCT y1.chClientCode, y1.nvcClientName,  y2.chClientCode,  y2.nvcClientName
FROM core.tblclient y1
  JOIN core.tblclient y2 On RIGHT(y1.CHCLIENTCODE,7)= RIGHT(y2.CHCLIENTCODE,7)
 WHERE y1.CHCLIENTCODE like 'M%' AND y2.CHCLIENTCODE like '7%'

Comment: Great man.. Mark it as right answer and give an upvote if my code helped you ..  that will help me in increasing my points.. :);P

Comment: Hi  Unnikrishnan, I would like to, but I am not able at this point because I jsut created the account -- 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score'